# Match hour:minute time format with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I am parsing a PDF banking statement file one line at a time. The problem is that the format is not always consistent.

Sometimes I have a string as this:

```
'Received from SOMEONE           11/02/2020   13∶20     $ 997,63   $ 997,63            -'
```

I am using Python 3 and I need to split the string using a time regex so I can have 2 strings, so the expected result would be:

```
['Received from SOMEONE           11/02/2020   ', '13∶20     $ 997,63   $ 997,63            -'
```

Among many others, I have tested the following regexes:

- `r"\s+(?=\d+\d+:\d+\d\s)"`
- `r"(?:(?:(\d+):)?(\d+))"`
- `r"(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])"`
- `r"(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d))"`

Could anyone please help me with the right regex to achieve what I need?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `re.findall(r'^(.*?)\s+(\b(?:2[0-3]|1[0-9]|0?[1-9])\b.*)$', text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split using a lookahead that asserts a time like pattern:

```
(?=(?:\b[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vogkXP/1)

Note that when I copy the example data the `∶` is this char https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2236 and in the regex I have used this `:` char https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+003A

If you want to match both, you could use a character class `[:∶]`

```
(?=(?:\b[01]\d|2[0-3])[:∶][0-5]\d\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/huFwPs/1)

```
import re

regex = r"(?=(?:\b[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d\b)"

test_str = "Received from SOMEONE           11/02/2020   13:20     $ 997,63   $ 997,63            -"
print(re.split(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
['Received from SOMEONE           11/02/2020   ', '13:20     $ 997,63   $ 997,63            -']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is exactly what you need:

```py
import re
s = 'Received from SOMEONE           11/02/2020   13∶20     $ 997,63   $ 997,63            -'
print(re.findall('(.+?\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})\s*(.+)',s)[0])
```

The regex string can be explained as follows: **Anything** `.+?` followed by a **date** `\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}` followed by **some space** `\s*` followed by **anything** `.+`

Output:

```
('Received from SOMEONE           11/02/2020', '13∶20     $ 997,63   $ 997,63            -')
```

Comment: Thanks, however the format is very weird. Depending on the data, one "logical" line can be divided up into 3 crlf lines and sometimes the date does not follow the time, so I need to split on time only as the other answer suggests.